# Use variable in sqlalchemy ilike statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-like

I am trying to query my `database` to find all items that match my variable `received_input`.

At the moment I have:

```
session.query(VenueItem).filter(VenueItem.venue_item_name.ilike("%received_input%")).all()
```

The items in my `database` may contain `uppercase` and `lowercase` characters. I need to ensure that the search is `case-insensitive` (`"ApPle"` would return from `input` of `"apple"`).

I don't know the syntax to specify a `variable` in `ilike` as opposed to a `string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `"%received_input%"` with

```
'%{}%'.format(received_input)
```

On python 3.6+, this can be written more concisely using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/?):

Example:

```
f'%{received_input}%'
```

Comment: thanks, will update the answer to also show how to do it with f-strings.